# How to set jlabel text to value of loop iterate "i"?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

```
if (numFac == 2 || numFac ==3){
    jLabel3.setText("Prime!"); }

    for ( i=3; i <=numFac; i++ ){
        double n = numFac%i;
            if (n==1 || n!=0){
            jLabel3.setText("Prime!"); 
            break;  }

            else {
                jLabel2.setText("The Divisors of " +numFac +" are ");
                for( i = 1; i <= numFac; i++)
                    {
                    if(numFac%i == 0)
                        { jLabel3.setText(i+" "); }      
            }

}
```

I am having a problem in displaying `i` in a `jlabel3`. I want it to display just like this:  `System.out.print(i+" ");`

Comment: **what** problem are you having?

Comment: and what's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Just get the current text and append the new number.

```
jLabel3.setText(jLabel3.getText() + i + " ");
```

Or, store the text in a variable:

```
String text = "";
...
text += i + " ";
jLabel3.setText(text);
```